# Libgdx - Box2D: Attach Physics Body Editor Loader mask to dynamic texture

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, game-physics

I have a texture of a circle, which gets drawn to a new position when a touch drag occurs. It isn’t set up as a body.

I have made a physics map using Aurelien Ribon's Physics Body Editor Loader GUI to the circle's upper and lower part, and I’d like to draw that mask over the texture’s position, and to its new position when a drag occurs.

How can I do this? In my create method I initialize the variables, the mask gets drawn to the texture’s initial position, but when I move it the mask stays at the circle’s initial position.

Here's my code:

`Create()` method:

```
 //... rest of the method ommited for clarity

    karika = gameWorld.getKarika();

    World world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), false);


Box2DDebugRenderer renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    BodyEditorLoader karikaLoader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/collision-masks/karika.json"));

    BodyDef karikaDef = new BodyDef();
    karikaDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    karikaDef.position.set(karika.getPosition().x, karika.getPosition().y);
    karikaDef.angle = karika.getRotation();

    Body karikaBody = world.createBody(karikaDef);

    FixtureDef karikaFixture = new FixtureDef();
    karikaFixture.density = 0.5f;
    karikaFixture.friction = 0.8f;
    karikaFixture.restitution = 0.6f;

    karikaLoader.attachFixture(karikaBody, "karika", karikaFixture, karika.getWidth());
    Vector2 karikaBodyOrigin = karikaLoader.getOrigin("karika", karika.getWidth()).cpy();

    //rest of the method ommited for clarity
```

My `render()` method:

```
 //...
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(karikaTexture, karika.getPosition().x, karika.getPosition().y, karika.getWidth() / 2, karika.getHeight() / 2, karika.getWidth(), karika.getHeight(), 1, 1, karika.getRotation(), 0, 0, karikaTexture.getWidth(), karikaTexture.getHeight(), false, false);
    batch.end();
renderer.render(world, cam.combined);
    world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
    //...
```

The texture that is being drawn in the render method is my circle's texture. As said before, I haven't set that up as a body, only the collision mask.

What I'd like to do, is *attach* the mask to the texture, and keep up with it's position, for example when I drag the circle, the mask should stay *on* the circle.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [DebugRenderer](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Box2DDebugRenderer.html). It works very well, and does precisely what you're asking.

Here's how to use it.

```
debugRenderer.render(this.world, camera.combined);
```

And here's [a more thorough tutorial](http://rotatingcanvas.com/using-box2d-debug-renderer-in-libgdx/).

I recommend you assign your circle's position using physics object's position rather than trying to assign the physics object to your texture's position.

In your code, it looks like you create your `karikaBody` using the current position of `karika`, but the `karikaBody` position is never being updated after that. So your "collision mask" (your physics body) position never changes.

Comment: I actually use DebugRenderer, I updated the code with it. Sadly, it doesn't work.. But maybe you didn't understand correctly. Here's what happens: http://tinyurl.com/kx6n9yd . If I move the circle away, the mask doesn't update it's position to the circle's position

Comment: What is variable `karika` retrieved by `gameWorld.getKarika()`?

Comment: Karika is the circle. It's based on my Entity class. Then, the entity class has a subclass named moveableentity (because i have more moveable entities) which's subclass is karika. It has a width, heoght, position, rotation and speed parameters. Gamewolrd isjust a wrapper, it has getters of karika and some other objects

Comment: I can't assign my texture the position of my physics body, since the physics body's position depends on the position of the circle. The second sentence however makes sense. Where, and how can I update karikaBody's position? (or the karikaDef's?) I tried putting my entire code that's in the create() method into the render() method, but it just started to create physics bodies on every loop of the render() method. Any suggestions? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I made it work with this line of code in my render method: karikaBody.setTransform(karika.getPosition().x, karika.getPosition().y, karika.getRotation()); However I feel like this isn't the best way to do it. What do you think?